# Python pandas: Calculating time difference based on conditions

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
ID Product Time
34 X       2020-07-02 00:00:04
38 Y       2020-07-02 00:00:05
40 X       2020-07-02 00:00:06
43 Y       2020-07-02 00:00:07
```

I want to create an additional column that gives me the time since the first ID for every product was tracked.
So my dataframe should look like this:

```
ID Product Time                  Time_since_first_ID
34 X       2020-07-02 00:00:04   00:00:00
38 Y       2020-07-02 00:00:05   00:00:00
40 X       2020-07-02 00:00:06   00:00:02
43 Y       2020-07-02 00:00:07   00:00:02
```

I know how to create a new column and how to create datetime format objects, but I don't know how to build in the condition that it is the time for the specific product.

Greatly appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do [`transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html#transformation):

```
df['time_since'] = df.groupby('Product')['Time'].transform(lambda x: x - x.min())

print(df)

   ID Product                Time time_since
0  34       X 2020-07-02 00:00:04   00:00:00
1  38       Y 2020-07-02 00:00:05   00:00:00
2  40       X 2020-07-02 00:00:06   00:00:02
3  43       Y 2020-07-02 00:00:07   00:00:02
```

Comment: @YOLO Is there any disadvantage of `df['time_since'] = df.groupby('Product')['Time'].apply(lambda x: x - x.min())` in the context of this problem?

Comment: @Michelle if it helps, kindly accept and upvote the answer. thanks

Comment: @Grayrigel Not sure if I understood, what sort of disadvantage you mean

Comment: @YOLO I did upvote and it says that votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but not publicly displayed ;) Thanks for your help!